# Are there any really simple/limited scripting languages for the JVM/BSF?

Tags: scripting, jvm

I'm looking for a **really** simple / limited scripting language for the JVM or the [Bean Scripting Framework](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/index.html) but can't find any.

I need the following operators:

- +
- -
- *
- /
- maybe ** (power)
- maybe sqrt

... and the ability to define Double type variables to create expressions like

```
(A+B)/2
```

The script may not call any JVM code (maybe with the exception of a Math class, but that's optional).

What options do i have?

I know I could just write that kind of thing myself, but I would prefer a tested, stable and fast solution.
I tried [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) before and really like it... but it's hard no to give my users the full power over the JVM with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no language that are as simple as I need them, so I will define one myself using ANTLR. The best example I found so far is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042353/extending-simple-antlr-grammer-to-support-input-variables/2042467#2042467).

Answer (score 2):

I think [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/) fits the bill.

Also, to create a sandbox for your expressions look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551073/how-do-you-create-a-secure-jexl-scripting-sandbox).

Comment: There were some recent posts to the JEXL mailing list about getting the power operator precedence to work right and I think it did not work correctly. Better check that out and see if it applies to you.

Answer (score 1):

check out [FScript](http://fscript.sourceforge.net/), maybe

Comment: looks like the best option yet, althrough they seem to allow access to java classes in the latest version. but I'll try using an older version of it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/). It's super simple and has the same syntax as Java (although you can generally use shorthand bean accesor notation). It's a great tool for embedding debugging and management capabilities into a running JVM.