# Antlr v3 java with user input

Tags: java, eclipse, input, antlr, antlr3

I would like to ask how to make input recognition for ANTLRv3 (especially v3.4) with Java Eclipse. 
From Antlr example here [ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/), the input has been initialized in the code. 
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("12*(5-6)");

What I wanted is the system could recognize/read user input and then do the calculation.

I have read this too: [Extending simple ANTLR grammer to support input variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042353/) but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly is giving you problems? The problem description "doesn't work for me" tells me nothing meaningful in order to help you.

Comment: Hmm sorry, I mean for the 
`public Double evaluate(String string, Map<String, Double> input) etc`. 
How to create the main test java to run that?

Comment: You create a class with a `main` method and for each line the user enters, you'll create a new parser and parse this input. You can feed the `Map` from the previous parse into the next parse. I suggest you try something before posting back: it's hard to help you without seeing what you've tried to solve it.