# How do you create a secure JEXL (scripting) sandbox?

Tags: java, jexl

I'm creating a sandbox for JEXL scripts to execute in so that a malicious user can't access data outside the variables we give them access to and also can't perform a DOS attack on the server. I'd like to document this for anybody else also doing this and also get other people's input into the approach.

The following is a list of the things I'm aware of that needs to be addressed:

1. Only allow instantiating classes using 'new' that are on a whitelist.
2. Do not allow accessing the getClass method on any class because then forName can be called and any class can be accessed.
3. Restrict access to resources such as files.
4. Allow an expression only a certain amount of time to execute so that we can limit the amount of resources it consumes.

This does not apply to JEXL but may apply to the scripting language you are using:

1. Do not allow an object to have a custom finalize method because the finalize method is called from the finalizer thread and will execute with the original AccessControlContext instead of the one being used to create the object and execute the code in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE: This was all done using JEXL 2.0.1. You may have to adapt this to make it work with newer versions.**

Here is my approach for dealing with each of these cases. I've created unit tests to test each of these cases and I have verified that they work.

1. JEXL makes this pretty easy. Just create a custom ClassLoader. Override the two loadClass() methods. On JexlEngine call setClassLoader().
2. Again, JEXL makes this pretty easy. You must block both '.class' and '.getClass()'. Create your own Uberspect class which extends UberspectImpl. Override getPropertyGet, if identifier equals "class" return null. Override getMethod, if method equals "getClass" return null. When constructing JexlEngine pass a reference to your Uberspect implementation.

   ```
   class MyUberspectImpl extends UberspectImpl {

       public MyUberspectImpl(Log jexlLog) {
           super(jexlLog);
       }

       @Override
       public JexlPropertyGet getPropertyGet(Object obj, Object identifier, JexlInfo info) {
           // for security we do not allow access to .class property
           if ("class".equals(identifier)) throw new RuntimeException("Access to getClass() method is not allowed");
           JexlPropertyGet propertyGet = super.getPropertyGet(obj, identifier, info);
           return propertyGet;
       }

       @Override
       public JexlMethod getMethod(Object obj, String method, Object[] args, JexlInfo info) {
           // for security we do not allow access to .getClass() method
           if ("getClass".equals(method)) throw new RuntimeException("Access to getClass() method is not allowed");
           return super.getMethod(obj, method, args, info);
       }

   }
   ```
3. You do this using Java's AccessController mechanism. I'll give a quick run-down of doing this. Start java with -Djava.security.policy=policyfile. Make a file named policyfile containing this line:
   grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
   Set the default SecurityManager with this call: System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager()); Now you can control permissions and your app by default has all permissions. It would be better if you limit the permissions of your app to only what it requires of course. Next, create an AccessControlContext that limits the permissions to the bare minimum and call AccessController.doPrivileged() and pass the AccessControlContext, then execute the JEXL script inside doPrivileged(). Here is a small program that demonstrates this. The JEXL script calls System.exit(1) and if it isn't wrapped in doPrivileged() it would successfully terminate the JVM.

   ```
   System.out.println("java.security.policy=" + System.getProperty("java.security.policy"));
   System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
   try {
       Permissions perms = new Permissions();
       perms.add(new RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers"));
       ProtectionDomain domain = new ProtectionDomain(new CodeSource( null, (Certificate[]) null ), perms );
       AccessControlContext restrictedAccessControlContext = new AccessControlContext(new ProtectionDomain[] { domain } );

       JexlEngine jexlEngine = new JexlEngine();
       final Script finalExpression = jexlEngine.createScript(
               "i = 0; intClazz = i.class; "
               + "clazz = intClazz.forName(\"java.lang.System\"); "
               + "m = clazz.methods; m[0].invoke(null, 1); c");

       AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
           @Override
           public Object run() throws Exception {
               return finalExpression.execute(new MapContext());
           }
       }, restrictedAccessControlContext);
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
4. The trick with this is interrupting the script before it finishes. One way I found to do this is to create a custom JexlArithmetic class. Then override each method in that class and before calling the real method in the super class check if the script should stop executing. I'm using an ExecutorService to create threads. When Future.get() is called pass the amount of time to wait. If a TimeoutException is thrown call Future.cancel() which interrupts the Thread running the script. Inside each overridden method in the new JexlArithmetic class check Thread.interrupted() and if true throw java.util.concurrent.CancellationException.
   Is there a better location to put code which will get executed regularly as a script is being executed so that it can be interrupted?

Here is an excerpt of the MyJexlArithmetic class. You have to add all the other methods:

```
    public class MyJexlArithmetic extends JexlArithmetic {

        public MyJexlArithmetic(boolean lenient) {
            super(lenient);
        }

        private void checkInterrupted() {
            if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new CancellationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object left, Object right) {
            checkInterrupted();
            return super.equals(left, right); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public Object add(Object left, Object right) {
            checkInterrupted();
            return super.add(left, right);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I am instantiating JexlEngine:

```
        Log jexlLog = LogFactory.getLog("JEXL");
        Map <String, Object> functions = new HashMap();
        jexlEngine = new JexlEngine(new MyUberspectImpl(jexlLog), new MyJexlArithmetic(false), functions, jexlLog);
```

Comment: How do you handle `forName` situation that can exploit the script to malicious intent? Also Uberspect didn't help. Or may be I am using it wrong. I created a JexlEngine which has custom Uberspect class, but it never verifies the usage of `.class`.

Comment: I'll add a little more info on my implementation. Also, I am certain I am using a much older version of JEXL than you are.